# how to anchor length as the number periods elapsed since a given bar

Tags: pine-script

In Pine there are plenty of built-in functions where the number of periods is fixed, e.g. moving averages.

Is there a way to code a moving average whose number of periods is not fixed?
(The common term for this might be a "dynamic length", or "variable length", instead of a "fixed length").

For example, let's say I want to be able to anchor the moving average to a specific bar, so that the number of periods averaged is always the same as the number of bars elapsed since the anchor bar.

For a strategy, it might look like this *pseudo*:

```
var anchor= ta.barssince(condition)
anchored_average = *ama*(ohlc4, anchor)
```

The lack of build-ins for this purpose has been mentioned before (*); I don't know whether it's been resolved.

TV do have a drawing tool "Anchored VWAP" among the Trend Line Tools, which seems to do something like this, but I can't see how it's code (2) could work in a strategy

(1)
https://www.tradingview.com/script/Sh7QBk3z-Examples-of-Rolling-Average-Using-Automated-Anchoring/

(2)
https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/pine-scripts-are-now-interactive-27147/

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of built-in functions nowadays that allow for dynamic length parameter.
See [Can I use a variable length in functions?](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#can-i-use-a-variable-length-in-functions) for some of those functions.

Excerpt:

> You can use a “series int” length (so a length that varies from bar to
> bar) in the following Pine functions: alma(), bb(), bbw(), cci(),
> change(), cmo(), cog(), correlation(), dev(), falling(), highest(),
> highestbars(), linreg(), lowest(), lowestbars(), mfi(), mom(),
> percentile_linear_interpolation(), percentile_nearest_rank(),
> percentrank(), rising(), roc(), sma(), stdev(), stoch(), sum(),
> variance(), vwma(), wma() and wpr().

Example for [ta.alma()](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_ta%7Bdot%7Dalma) below.
You can see that `length` is a `series(int)` parameter, which means you can have a variable length, whereas the `offset` parameter is a `simple int` whichs means it has to be a fixed value.

[image: ta.alma()]

Comment: Thanks; I need to do some more work on that.  For the moment I am using the code below to anchor to the first bar:   `origin = ta.barssince(barstate.isfirst == true)`